# What cloudbuild.yaml "gcloud app deploy" uses?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

The subject basically says it all.

I am using `gcloud app deploy` but I'd like to tweak the build process, is there a way to get the cloudbuild.yaml file that is used by default to have something to start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps if you already have a app deployed to find the '*cloudbuild.yaml*' file:

1. Open Cloud shell.
2. On the Cloud Shell window menu bar click 'Open Terminal' and click 'Open in a New Window'.
3. In the new Editor window, you have Search option on the left pane, use it to find the file.

To create a basic build config file follow this guide:

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration